# Animation in jquery similar to marquee

Tags: jquery, marquee

I want to move more than one ball image in alternative behavior of HTML.(exactly like the screen saver ball m  If i use marquee tag means, it doesn't cross each other. Both moving around separately with the div.

It should move around the div and if i place more than one image, those both images should cross each other..

Please give me the code snippet for this along with the jquery version.

Answer (score 3):

[jScroller is a nice tool for a similar effect.](http://jscroller.markusbordihn.de/)

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you to go with this. It's really lightweight!

http://tonysamperi.github.io/endlessRiver/

Endless river is a jQuery plugin, that animates content and make it scroll endlessly!

The usefull feature is that you don't have to set widths to elements, because speed is set in pixel/second!!

EndlessRiver will calculate the best width for the *<li>* element and keep speed constant!

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)

Comment: Good to know! I'll add info to the answer!

Comment: Why the downvote? The previous answer is not available anymore! That's why I decided to post a new one!

Comment: I haven't downvoted FWIW, I just mentioned link only. I have no idea of the content and so can't comment on that.